# What exactly happens when these lines of code is run + iPhone

Tags: iphone

```
VisitWebsiteVC *visitWebSite = [[[VisitWebsiteVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"VisitWebsiteVC" bundle:nil] retain];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:visitWebSite animated:YES];
            [visitWebSite dealloc];
```

What will happen due to  [visitWebSite dealloc].

Comment: Never, ever, ever, ever, ever, ever call dealloc explicitly

Comment: "What will happen due to [visitWebSite dealloc]." nothing good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you should NEVER invoke the dealloc method (except [super dealloc] in dealloc).

You code should throw a BAD_ACCESS exception

(Retain count)
Alloc = 1
Retain +1 = 2
Push +1 = 3
Dealloc = 0

But you VisitWebsiteVC instance is still in use by the navigation controller

What you should do is :

```
VisitWebsiteVC *visitWebSite = [[VisitWebsiteVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"VisitWebsiteVC" bundle:nil];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:visitWebSite animated:YES];
            [visitWebSite release];
```